# Rails: How do I require ActiveSupport's rescue_from method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, activesupport

I have this code in `application controller`:

```
# Method to capture and handle all exceptions
rescue_from Exception do |ex|
  Rails.logger.debug ex
  do_stuff(ex)
end
```

I want to move this into a module and then:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include 'module'
...
```

Right now my module looks like:

```
# lib/exception_mailer.rb
require 'action_mailer'
require 'active_support'

module ExceptionMailer

  # Method to capture and handle all exceptions
  rescue_from Exception do |ex|
...
```

And I am getting: `undefined method 'rescue_from' for ExceptionMailer:Module`

I've googled 'how do i include rescue_from in a module?' -- and I'm still a little lost.

Comment: This link might help you out. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from

Comment: I think I found a solution doing `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` and using an `included do` block. Rails is a dependency of my gem. I'm not currently needing to require anything.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
module Exceptionailer
  # http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rescue_from Exception do |ex|
      ...
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Adding `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` and using an `included do` block fixed the issue for me.