# Rails add 'rescue_from' method to application controller from patch//plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to patch the **ApplicationController** of my Rails(4.2.5) application  from a plugin.
I want to add 'rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound' to my ApplicationController.Ways I have tried till now:

1.

```
module ApplicationControllerPatch
            def self.included(base) 
            base.class_eval do
                rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
                    redirect_to root_path
                end
            end
        end
    end

ApplicationController.send(:include, ApplicationControllerPatch)
```

2.

```
module ApplicationControllerPatch
    def self.included(base) 
        base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
        base.class_eval do
            rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found
        end
    end
    module InstanceMethods
        def not_found
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end
end

ApplicationController.send(:include, ApplicationControllerPatch)
```

3. Solution in this stack overflow link: 
   [How do I require ActiveSupport's rescue_from method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048483/how-do-i-require-activesupports-rescue-from-method)

None of the ways seem to work till now.
Please provide any solution or help in correcting if there is a mistake in the above code.

Comment: Just include a module in ApplicationController instead of attempting to monkeypatch it from the outside. Otherwise you have to worry about when the monkeypatch is executed.

Comment: I cannot change the code in core rails application,hence need to monkey patch.

Answer (score 2):

Here I have done the same thing and tested it is working well for me. Below is my module. I have added into Application**lib/exception_data_redirection**

```
module ExceptionDataRedirection
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
      redirect_to items_path
    end
  end
 end
```

**items_path** will be the redirect url

In application.rb -- add the following lines

```
 config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Restart the server....

Then ApplicationController -- include the module

```
  include ExceptionDataRedirection
```

This worked like a charm ,You can do like this also

```
module ExceptionDataRedirection

  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
        redirect_to items_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Kindly let me know If there is any issues